# Возможно ли постепенно закрашивать UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Имеется `UIPageViewController` с тремя страницами. Каждая страница разного цвета (`backgroundColor`). На каждой страничке `pageControl` должен быть разного цвета. В данный момент цвета меняется при скроллинге, когда изменяется pageControl.currentPage.

```
pageControl?.pageIndicatorTintColor = ...
pageControl?.currentPageIndicatorTintColor =  ...
```

Вопрос такой, возможно ли менять цвет постепенно? То есть если пользователь медленно скроллит вью, то "точка" закрашивается постепенно. Пример на картинке, экран голубой, далее переключается на розовый. И та часть "точки", которая уже на розовом фоне должна быть другого цвета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: раскопать точку во вью иерархии и руками с ней делать что хочется

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: Вот такой эффект надо получить: https://github.com/donnellyk/KVNMaskedPageControl

Comment: а почему бы тогда не использовать этот самый код?

Comment: надо на swift =)

Comment: совсем разленился :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну если лень переписывать руками, то что предложил Max Mikheyenko, то можешь создать кастомную UIView с 3-мя точками и уже дальше на каждом из PageView задавать нужный цвет нужной точке :)